# Show that $\sup[a,b]=b$

Tags: real-analysis

Obviously, $b\geq x$ for any $x$ in $[a,b]$. So, $\sup[a,b]\leq b$. We will show that $\sup[a,b]$ cannot be strictly less than $b$. Suppose $\sup[a,b]=s<b$. **But, then as $s$ is an upper bound for $[a,b]$, we have $b\leq s$.** This contradicts $s<b$.

I couldn't understand bold-face sentence. How did we obtain $b\leq s$ ?

Comment: Because $b\in [a,b]$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli But, we assumed $sup[a,b]=s<b$.

Comment: Yes, it has been assumed *as a contradiction* that $\sup [a,b]<b$. Then you prove that it is inconsistent with the defining property of supremum as "the least upper bound of the set".

Answer (score 1):

Think of a supremem as a least upper bound. It is the smallest possible thing that is bigger than everything in the set. Anything smaller, you can find something larger in the set.

The bolded sentence: you're assuming $s$ is a supremum (least upper bound) for the set $[a,b]$. We have $b \leq s$ since $b$ is in the set $[a,b]$, for which $s$ is assumed to be the supremum.

Comment: Okey, thanks...

Comment: Does it make sense? Is there anything else I can clarify?

Comment: I understood: We assumed sup$[a,b]=s<b$. But, by the definition, since $s$ is least upper bound then it must be an upper bound for $[a,b]$. Then, we have $b\leq s$ because $b$ is max element in the set. So, this contrudicts $s<b$ ?

Comment: Yes, and since we assumed $s < b$ we must thus have $b \leq s$.

Answer (score 1):

The bold text reflects the fact that any supremum must be greater than or equal to any element in the set. We have $b \in [a,b]$, so if $s$ is the supremum it must be greater than or equal to $b$ (and all other members of $[a,b]$).

Here is another way to think of the problem. The $\sup$ of a set $E$, call it $\alpha$, satisfies:

$$
\alpha - \epsilon < x \leq \alpha
$$

for some $x \in E$ and for all $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose $b < \alpha$. Then let $\epsilon = \alpha - b$. The inequality becomes:

$$
b < x \leq \alpha.
$$

Clearly there is no $x \in [a, b]$ that is greater than $b$! So $\alpha \leq b$. If $\alpha < b$, then you can show that you can pick an element of $[a,b]$ greater than $\alpha$ pretty easily, so $\alpha$ cannot be an upper bound, contradicting our supposition than $\alpha$ is the supremum. The only option left is that $b=\alpha$, our supremum!